# Is there a way to change content in a modal more efficiently?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll

I'm building a portfolio site and I'm working on a work/project section. Right now, I have a bunch of thumbnails that opens up a modal, but I want the content of the modal to change content depending on what thumbnail was pressed, without me having to keep duplicating the modal code.

This is the code for the thumbnails:

```
<div class="thumb-container">
    {% for project in site.data.settings.projects %}
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="thumb-unit" style="background-image: url(assets/img/work/{{ project.folder }}/thumb.png);">
            <div class="thumb-overlay">
                <strong>{{ project.name }}</strong>
                <!--<div class="zoom-icon"></div>-->
            </div>
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is the modal code. It doesn't really work because when I click on a thumbnail, a modal for each project pops up instead of just the one corresponding to the thumb. And I know its because its a loop, I just wanted to show what I had.

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    {% for project in site.data.settings.projects %}
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{ project.name }}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            {% include {{project.file}} %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So, I think the issue is that I can't figure out how to somehow tell the modal which content to show. if anyone could help me out, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to set one modal per project :

#### Set a different target id for each button by using the `forloop.index`

```
<div class="thumb-container">
  {% for project in site.data.settings.projects %}
    <a href="#myModal{{ forloop.index }}" data-toggle="modal" class="thumb-unit" style="background-image: url(assets/img/work/{{ project.folder }}/thumb.png);">
```

#### Create one modal per project and give him a unique id by using the `forloop.index`

```
<!-- Modals -->
  {% for project in site.data.settings.projects %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{ forloop.index }}" ...
```

You can of course save some html code by using only one modal for all project (See bootstrap documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)). But, I think it adds useless complexity.